# Removing Privileges on Missing databases

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I deleted a bunch of databases but forgot to revoke privileges for certain user... What is easiest way to get list of databases that don't exist but user has privileges on, so i can foreach that array and revoke privileges on (found_list) from my user?

Comment: By looking into the internal database `mysql` inside a mysql database management system. That is where the permissions are defined. Check the tables `db` and `user` and compare that against the output of the query `SHOW DATABASES;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SCHEMATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/schemata-table.html) and [SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/schema-privileges-table.html) tables in [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html):

```
SELECT * FROM schema_privileges 
 LEFT JOIN  schemata ON (catalog_name=table_catalog and schema_name=TABLE_SCHEMA) 
 WHERE schema_name IS NULL;
```

This will give you privileges that were granted for tables that don't exist anymore. It may not take into account certain permissions give using wildcards so please pay attention on output.

Comment: full answer (list of granted nonexistant databases):

`USE information_schema; SELECT table_schema FROM schema_privileges LEFT JOIN  schemata ON (catalog_name=table_catalog and schema_name=TABLE_SCHEMA) WHERE schema_name IS NULL AND grantee='user@'host' GROUP BY table_schema`;